# Why does Java use (hash & 0x7FFFFFFF) % tab.length to decide the index of a key?

Tags: java, algorithm, hashtable

From the link below, I know Java uses `(hash & 0x7FFFFFFF) % tab.length` to decide which slot of an array to put the {key, value} in.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Hashtable.java#Hashtable.put%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29

My question is why Java first does hash & 0x7FFFFFFF? Is there any particular purpose?

Comment: I would assume it is to make sure that the key is always a positive integer, so that you don't attempt to use a negative array index.

Comment: Suppose it wouldn't. For example, what is -12345678 % 37?

Comment: is "hash & (tab.length - 1)" of ConcurrentHashMap is same as "(hash & 0x7FFFFFFF) % tab.length" of hashtable ?

Comment: in C# is a same: 
1. int hashCode = comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
2. int targetBucket = hashCode % buckets.Length;

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Because `-1 % 10 == -1` which you certainly don't want for indexing into an array. Forcing the sign bit to 0 avoids this problem.

Comment: yeah, damn it, I forgot the possible negative hashCode. thanks

Comment: @plzdontkillme because math.abs doesn't always return a positive number. Also depending on compiler and architecture it's either a bit more or quite a lot more efficient.

Comment: @plzdontkillme to elaborate, Math.abs(-2^-31) is -2^-31 because there is no 2^31.

Answer (score 49):

Because:

- `0x7FFFFFFF` is 0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 : all 1 except the sign bit.
- `(hash & 0x7FFFFFFF)` will result in a positive integer.
- `(hash & 0x7FFFFFFF) % tab.length` will be in the range of the tab length.

Comment: +1 Good Explanation. However I have a doubt. is "hash & (tab.length - 1)" of ConcurrentHashMap is same as "(hash & 0x7FFFFFFF) % tab.length" of hashtable ?

Comment: Excellent Explanation!

Comment: Perfect explanation. I dont even need this for this code but it make sense for something similar  im looking at. Thank you!

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar You can't be sure (tab.length -1) will be positive so it's a dangerous code in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

Note that `Hashtable` is more or less outdated and was replaced by `HashMap`. This one uses `hash & (table.length-1)` to achieve the same purpose.

It also does some bit shifting before as can be seen [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.hash%28int%29). This is to cope with bad implementations of the `hashCode()` method which return numbers with a low diversity.